# Fazer pedido de filmes por link IMDB

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite, venho aqui questionar a comunidade do **SO** se alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo, quando inserimos um link do *IMDB* no **input** e damos submit, ele adiciona o filme a lista de pedidos como na imagem..

Comment: Não deu pra entender a sua pergunta direito, poderia detalhar melhor?

Comment: **EX: quando eu adiciono o link do IMDB no input, automaticamente insere a capa ali ao lado** Pense num sistema de pedir filmes/series, é assim mesmo como na imagem

Comment: Só prevenindo uma provável reação: sua pergunta é por "alguma idéia". Quando tiver um código específico, abra uma nova pergunta ;)

Answer (score 1):

Parece que o IMDB tem duas APIs, ambas completamente não-documentadas, procurei em todo FAQ do site e não achei nada (6 anos depois da pergunta original abaixo no SOen).
*Vide [**Does IMDB provide an API?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1966503/1287812)*

Uma estática e cacheada, tentei fazer alterações mas quase nenhuma funcionou:

- http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/b/bb.json
- http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/h/hello.json

E outra mais avançada:

- por nome: http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q=odete+lara
- por título: http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?xml=1&nr=1&tt=on&q=cidade+deus

O Google mostra este serviço como primeiro resultado para IMDB + API, parece não-oficial:

- [OMDb API - The Open Movie Database](http://www.omdbapi.com/)

<sub>PS: cuidado com fazer scrapping ou tentar puxar esses dados de maneira "alternativa", as penalidades são bem altas e o pessoal da indústria de cinema/música não brinca em serviço.</sub>

Comment: O conteudo dentro deste link **http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/h/hello.json** , nunca percebi como colocar isto em texto devidamente indexado. Ex: Nome: Filme, Ano: 200. Será que me pode dar uma ajuda em relacao a isso?

Comment: Já vi, mas "retirar" uma imagem de um site nao tem problema algum (suponho eu)

Comment: É, a capa/cartaz do filme é material de divulgação, em teoria é bom que seja reproduzida por aí.